# Installing juju gui on juju1.25.5 (ERROR cannot load cookies)

Tags: juju, maas, openstack, openstack-autopilot

I'm trying to get JUJU Gui deployed but I cannot.  I've found other posts with the same issue, citing this bug.

[Cookies file locked for too long](https://bugs.launchpad.net/juju-core/+bug/1534643)

The bug was fixed in 1.25.4, however, I'm on 1.25.5 and still having the same issue.  Anyone else experience this?

```
landscape@juju-machine-0-lxc-1:/var/log/juju$ juju deploy juju-gui
ERROR cannot load cookies: file locked for too long; giving up
landscape@juju-machine-0-lxc-1:/var/log/juju$ juju deploy --to 0 juju-gui
ERROR cannot load cookies: file locked for too long; giving up


 [Machines] 
    ID         STATE   VERSION DNS         INS-ID                                                         SERIES HARDWARE                          
    0          started 1.25.5  node00.maas /MAAS/api/1.0/nodes/node-0c195d0a-1837-11e6-b5b2-0015c5efa6ff/ trusty arch=amd64 cpu-cores=4 mem=16384M 
    1          started 1.25.5  node01.maas /MAAS/api/1.0/nodes/node-81978dfc-185c-11e6-b442-0015c5efa6ff/ trusty arch=amd64 cpu-cores=8 mem=32768M 
    2          started 1.25.5  node03.maas /MAAS/api/1.0/nodes/node-857a9eaa-185c-11e6-86a5-0015c5efa6ff/ trusty arch=amd64 cpu-cores=8 mem=32768M 
    3          started 1.25.5  node02.maas /MAAS/api/1.0/nodes/node-8304f3a0-185c-11e6-9f9d-0015c5efa6ff/ trusty arch=amd64 cpu-cores=8 mem=32768M 



landscape@juju-machine-0-lxc-1:/var/log/juju$ juju status --format summary
Running on subnets: 10.14.0.101/8 
Utilizing ports:    123/udp, 27017/tcp, 27019/tcp, 
                    27021/tcp, 28017/tcp, 3333/tcp, 
                    443/tcp, 5672/tcp, 80/tcp, 
                    8773/tcp, 8774/tcp, 8777/tcp, 
                    9292/tcp, 9696/tcp 
           # MACHINES: (4)
              started:  4 

              # UNITS: (87)
              started:  87 

           # SERVICES:  (23)
          base-machine   0/1 exposed
            ceilometer   0/1 exposed
      ceilometer-agent   0/1 exposed
              ceph-mon   0/1 exposed
              ceph-osd   0/1 exposed
          ceph-radosgw   0/1 exposed
                cinder   0/1 exposed
                glance   0/1 exposed
              keystone   0/1 exposed
      landscape-client   0/1 exposed
               mongodb   0/1 exposed
                 mysql   0/1 exposed
                nagios   0/1 exposed
           neutron-api   0/1 exposed
       neutron-gateway   0/1 exposed
   neutron-openvswitch   0/1 exposed
 nova-cloud-controller   0/1 exposed
          nova-compute   0/1 exposed
                  nrpe   0/1 exposed
                   ntp   0/1 exposed
             ntpmaster   0/1 exposed
   openstack-dashboard   0/1 exposed
       rabbitmq-server   0/1 exposed
```

Answer (score 0):

The bug was confirmed and reopened.

[[Bug 1534643] Re: cookies file locked for too long](https://bugs.launchpad.net/juju-core/+bug/1534643)

Answer (score 0):

In the meanwhile, if you are doing test-and-dev, would love your feedback on the Juju 2.0 beta. The latest version (b7) seems to work well with LXD and I think the public clouds, too. In 2.0 the GUI is part of the base controller, so all you have to do is:

$ juju autoload-credentials
  $ juju bootstrap  aws
  $ juju gui

See if that works well for you.

Comment: Thanks, @mark-shuttleworth - I've taken an interest in JUJU 2.0 since it started to support MAAS 2.0, or vice versa.  In any matter, I look forward to firing up a new environment and taking advantage of the latest.  16.04, MAAS 2.0, JUJU 2.0, Openstack Mitaka.